# Як правильно: людвісарня чи людвисарня?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, іменники

У статті [РОЛЬ МИТЦІВ - ТВОРЦІВ САКРАЛЬНОГО ПРОСТОРУ](http://bo0k.net/index.php?p=achapter&bid=13154&chapter=1) подають такий варіант:

> Львівський відливник Франке (Франкович) Андрій (?-1668), син Георгія Франке, який працював у 40-60-х роках XVII в **людвісарні** біля Галицької брами, створив дзвін 1654 для домініканського монастиря...

Б. Кіндратюк у монографії [Дзвонарська культура України](https://ru.calameo.com/read/002820791aaae6a650974) використовує іншу форму слова:

> [...] стисло описав історію декількох **людвисарень** у Галичині.

Звернулася у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljudvysarnja), однак результату не отримала.

То як же правильно: ***людвисарня чи людвісарня***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [монографії Кіндратюк Б. Дзвонарська культура України](https://ru.calameo.com/books/002820791aaae6a650974) знаходимо використання **людвисарня**.

У [Енциклопедії українознавства. Словникова частина (ЕУ-II). — Париж, Нью-Йорк, 1955. — Т. 1. — С. 53-69](http://izbornyk.org.ua/encycl/euii007.htm)   у словниковій статті артилерія знаходимо використання слова **людвисарня**:

> Тут постала 1468 р. людвисарня (ливарня), яка постачала гармати на всю Україну.

У сучасних словниках це слово відсутнє. Натрапила також на цікаве [обговорення](http://tereveni.org/topic/30667/):

> Це полонізм: [ludwisarnia](https://sjp.pwn.pl/szukaj/ludwisarnia.html) - майстерня, де відливалися вироби з міді, бронзи або латуні, насамперед дзвони і гармати. З німецької Rotgießerei
>   Зараз _Ex почне доводити, що це споконвічне українське слово, привласнене поляками
>   За правилами української мови повинно писатися людвисарня, але навряд чи це слово потрапило до словників, бо в Україні стосується лише кількох історичних пам'яток Першої Речі Посполитої.

Очевидно, справді правильно **людвисарня.**